# Django : How can I fix this when adding facebook login to django app using social-auth?

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using django to create a web app and add facebook login in the homepage. But whenever I run click on the facebook login link, I get the following error. Can anyone tell me where the error is and how I can fix it ?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to [facebook developers](https://developers.facebook.com).
- Select your app.
- On the left menu choodse Facebook login -> Settings.
- In the "Valid OAuth redirect URI's" enter the proper URL.

It your site is `https://example.com` and you registerd all_auth app url's under `/accounts` the default callback URL should look like this:

```
https://example.com/accounts/facebook/login/callback/
```